# Nginx serving page through frameset

Tags: nginx, proxy, node.js

I'm using Nginx to serve proxy requests to nodejs running on port 3000. Here's my config:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name example.com;

  root /home/example/app;
  access_log /home/example/access.log;
  error_log /home/example/error.log;

  location / {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
  }
}
```

When I visit the site in my browser, I can see that the initial response from the server is a frameset, which in turns loads the page. All of this is unnoticeable to the user, until you hover over links and see the IP address instead of the actual URL. Here's the initial response (where 1.1.1.1 is my servers' actual IP address):

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
   "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>

<head>
  <title>My cool site</title>

</head>
<frameset rows="100%,*" border="0">
  <frame src="http://1.1.1.1" frameborder="0" />
  <frame frameborder="0" noresize />
</frameset>

<!-- pageok -->
<!-- 06 -->
<!-- -->
</html>
```

The next request is for the actual content. I've taken node js out of the equation by firing up a simple php script using php's built in server running on port 3000. I get the same issue.

I'm running nginx/1.4.6 (Ubuntu).

Comment: You have tested with two different web servers so you might conclude that the web server itself is not the issue. Could it be that the actual HTML page ( or the code that generates it) is a frame set page and there is nothing actually wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was not the server. It was the domain that was set to DNS masking. I checked via dig where the actual domain was pointed and noticed that it wasn't pointing to my server. It was pointing to a Godaddy server which was serving an inline frame which in turn loaded the actual page. I asked the client to remove the domain masking and it all works fine now.